# Rails 3 - Devise With OmniAuth - Redirect after signing in goes to /users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise, omniauth

Im using devise with omniauth for signing in users with facebook. I want them to be redirected after signing in to the page they were on after before signing in.

I've used the

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    store_location = session[:return_to]
    clear_stored_location
    (store_location.nil?) ? "/" : store_location.to_s
  end
```

in my application controller, and made a sessions_helper with this code

```
  def deny_access
    store_location
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end

  def anyone_signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  private

    def store_location
      session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    end

    def clear_stored_location
      session[:return_to] = nil
    end
```

And to fix the problem with being redirected to "services/" where I have the logic for the authentication with facebook and other platforms I've used the

```
skip_before_filter :store_location
```

in services and other controllers that I don't to be stored as locations.

Q1 The problem I'm having now is when I use ajax and render a login form in a modal window is that when a user successfully signs in it gets redirected to /users/sign_in/. I don't have a user controller and tried to make a sessions_controller.rb and added the skip_before... there but it doesn't work.

This is my routes for sign_in

```
new_user_session       GET   /users/sign_in(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    user_session      POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session   GET   /users/sign_out(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

Q2 I've tried to use the redirect when users sign out

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      (session[:return_to].nil?) ? "/" : session[:return_to].to_s
  end
```

But that only redirects me to the root page.

I really appreciate any help in this,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I answered this here

[Devise doesn't redirect properly to stored location when using omniauth provider like facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279387/devise-doesnt-redirect-properly-to-stored-location-when-using-omniauth-provider)

in application_controller.rb

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   if request.env['omniauth.origin']
      request.env['omniauth.origin']
    end
end
```

Comment: Seconded. This later answer is better than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: has this changed since '11, seems to be working for me now (i.e. devise does redirect properly)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either with Rails 4.2, Devise 3.2 and omniauth 1.2.2

Answer (score 3):

did you consider the Devise provided helper `sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)` (details can be found [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers))?  You also get `sign_out_and_redirect(resource_or_scope)` amongst others.

Q2. do try inspecting `session[:return_to]` - it's most likely `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter like: `/auth/facebook?referrer=/path/to/redirect`

After the Facebook authentication this parameter will be available to you in `env["omniauth.params"]`.