# Devise doesn't redirect properly to stored location when using omniauth provider like facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I have in my app some actions which are protected and need user authentication. Since I'm using devise, I use authenticate_user! before filter to protect them. Whenever user hits the protected page, devise ask the user to login and then redirects back to the protected page. This part works perfectly.

The problem is that when user tries to login with Facebook through my app, devise doesn't redirect the user to the protected page after login. It always throw the user back to root url. With standard authentication this is not a problem

I am suspecting it has something to do with passthru method which devise - omniauth integration requires. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my code snippet for omniauth callback:

```
def facebook
# You need to implement the method below in your model
omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(omniauth, current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end

def passthru
  render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
end
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem right now, and I can't seem to figure out how to integrate devise and omniauth together to redirect to the previous page.

Comment: is this code in your client or your provider?

Answer (score 10):

We use Facebook JS to get the access code which then returns back to 
the omniauth_callback_controller.rb and signs the user in.

I found that the origin URL is saved in the request.
Worked a treat for us.

in **application_controller.rb**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   if request.env['omniauth.origin']
      request.env['omniauth.origin']
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. There are few issues with using request.env['omniauth.origin'] and IE you can check out over here [link](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/306). Howevever, another issue is that the call to my protected request is an ajax one, so omniauth.origin doesn't reflect that but rather my last get request.

Comment: I am also trying to use the Facebook JS API with Devise. How are you passing the access code to omniauth_callback_controller?