# sign_in_and_redirect with omniauth-facebook to specific language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using `omniauth-facebook` gem with rails 3.2 and devise 2.0.

I have a website with 2 languages, english and spanish.

http://localhost:3000/en
http://localhost:3000/es

The gem works fine for **english users** because in **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** the redirect go to `http://localhost:3000/en`

This is my **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb** for facebook:

```
def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Then problem is for spanish users. that if they use `http://localhost:3000/es` the redirect from callback go to `http://localhost:3000/en`

I want that redirect from callback go to specific language that is using that user.

**How can I do it?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue, and did not find a way to change the callback url, but I could set the locale in the method when the callback happens.

The original url (which has the orignal correct locale) is in stored in `request.env['omniauth.origin']`

So in `facebook` method pick the locale from the original url, where it is in similar way the two letters after the domain part.

I added in the beginning of the `facebook` method:

```
I18n.locale = exctract_locale_from_url(request.env['omniauth.origin']) if request.env['omniauth.origin']
```

Where the `exctract_locale_from_url` is a horrible looking regexp :)

```
def exctract_locale_from_url(url)
  url[/^([^\/]*\/\/)?[^\/]+\/(\w{2})(\/.*)?/,2]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must extract your omniauth config to yaml file and insert "#{i18n.locale}" to the end of callback link.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have the same problem that this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279387/devise-doesnt-redirect-properly-to-stored-location-when-using-omniauth-provider. Can you write a example for solution please? Thank you!