# How do you get Devise to send a locale parameter to facebook

Tags: devise, localization, locale

I got it to keep the same locale in my Rails app, but I'd like it to pass the locale parameter   `?locale=es_ES` to user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path so that the facebook login page appears in Spanish

Comment: seems like this is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227136/sign-in-and-redirect-with-omniauth-facebook-to-specific-language

Comment: similar but not the same; my redirect back works fine. I need the facebook page to be in spanish. Simply: I want to redirect to https://www.facebook.com/login?locale=es_LA instead of https://www.facebook.com/login