# Redirect after new sign up using Devise & Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have been trying to set my app to redirect new registration/signups to a specific route within my app. I have used the devise docs that recommend creating a registrations controller in app/controllers/users/ and then use the

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 show_cities_path(resource)
end
```

but I havent had any luck, even after editing the routes file to include it.

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

I am currently using Twitter Omniauth with Devise.

My routes file is as followed:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

end

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def twitter
 auth = env["omniauth.auth"]

 @user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"],current_user)
 if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
 else
  session["devise.twitter_uid"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
end
```

Can anyone recommend an alternative method or tell me where I went wrong?

EDIT: Sorry may not have been clear. I already have the user model setup working using Devise and Omniauth. It is the overriding of where new registrations go.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial [link](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/).

Comment: @kendotwill yes. Sorry I may have not been clear. The user model works perfectly fine with Devise & Omniauth. I am just stuck with trying to override the redirect for when a new user registers.

Comment: what controller does `after_sign_up_path_for` method in? I think you should move it to application controller.

Comment: @KienThanh it lived in RegistrationsController < Devise:: RegistrationsController.

Comment: @Damien_Hogan, ok, you are not config devise to use your registration controller. you should specify it in your routes: `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }` . Take a look at [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) for more info.

Comment: Try adding a log statement to verify `after_sign_up_path_for` is being called. Also is it supposed to be `after_sign_up_path_for` or `after_sign_in_path_for`?

Comment: @KienThanh I tried that and still no luck.

Comment: @kendotwill It can be either of those according to devise docs. I am not convinced it is being called as I am using Omniauth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon research I found out that Devise doesnt redirectly properly when using Omniauth ([Devise doesn't redirect properly to stored location when using omniauth provider like facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279387/devise-doesnt-redirect-properly-to-stored-location-when-using-omniauth-provider)).

So I implemented this in my application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource.sign_in_count == 1
       new_product_path
    else
       root_path
    end
end
```

Upon their first login it will redirect them to path you want to on line 3 of the method.