# how to redirect after sign in with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I checked the official wiki: [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

I defined

```
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     return request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
   end
```

Somehow, it doesn't work at all.

After I sign in FB account with `omniauth`, the `request.env['omniauth.origin']` is `nil`.

I want `devise` to redirect according some conditions, e.g. the page user just visited before he visits the sign in page.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you already configured the Omniauth plugin to work with Facebook OAuth for authentication ? the request.env['omniauth.origin'] will work if you do a 'facebook login' with the help of omniauth and once you are able to successfully authenticate with facebook and facebook redirects to your application, that is when the request.env['omniauth.origin'] be set with the right value.

Comment: @DhruvaSagar can you write a example please? Thank you!

Comment: Check out this link Lai: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355107/rails-3-devise-with-omniauth-redirect-after-signing-in-goes-to-users-sign-i or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279387/devise-doesnt-redirect-properly-to-stored-location-when-using-omniauth-provider