# Devise Resetting Session On Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

I've got the following defined in my `application_controller.rb` file:

```
def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session.delete(:return_to)
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.url
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  r = session[:return_to] || user_root_url
  session.delete(:return_to)
  r
end
```

I'm trying to send a user back to the place they came from before the sign_in, or, if no location is saved, send them to their root page.

I call this in one of my controllers:

```
if current_user.nil?
  store_location
  redirect_to home_login_url, alert: "You must be logged in to purchase subscriptions"
  return
end
```

I stepped through the debugger and watched the `session[:return_to]` get set, but after I log on and the `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` is called, `session[:return_to]` is null.

How can I persist the `return_to` variable across a login?

I'm running Rails 3.2.1 and Devise 2.1.2

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that maybe devise uses that name in the session somewhere. I haven't tried it myself, but the answer here suggests a couple helper methods that might help you achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355107/rails-3-devise-with-omniauth-redirect-after-signing-in-goes-to-users-sign-i

Comment: @agmcleod - That lead me to an answer.  If you want to write your comment as an answer, I'll go ahead and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overwriting Devise's entry in my hash.  I think `:return_to` is what Devise uses.  I ended up implementing this completely differently, but look for name conflicts if you have a problem