# When does Devise store the location for stored_location_for_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, devise

I was having problems redirecting to the last visited page when that page required a sign in [Devise Resetting Session On Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257269/devise-resetting-session-on-login) and somebody pointed out that you could follow the code example here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

That example calls `stored_location_for(resource)`...where is that set?

That example works perfectly when used in conjunction with a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in my appropriate controllers.  Looking at the source code for `authenticate_#{resource}!`, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb it doesn't seem to save the location.

Where in the world is the previous location stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is stored in `session["user_return_to"]` (assuming `user` is your model name).

This appears to be set by `store_location!` in [failure_app.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L175)

Note that if you only have one devise model, the sign in redirect should work automatically, without you needing to override `after_sign_in_path_for` in your `application_controller.rb`.

Comment: Noticed the default `sign_in_path` would probably work, thanks for confirming that.